How to reference to another JSON Schema?
So I have 2 JSONs (simplified for easy understanding):
{
    "$schema":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id":"header.scm",
    "type":"object",
    "additionalProperties":false,
    "properties":{
        "id":{
            "type":"string",
            "pattern":"^[A-Z]*([0-9]{17})$"
        },
        "verb":{
            "type":"string",
            "enum":[
                "POST",
                "GET",
                "PUT",
                "PATCH",
                "DELETE"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required":[
        "id",
        "endpoint"
    ]
}

{
    "$schema":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id":"wms_mission.scm",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "header":{
            "$ref":"#C:/schemas/header.scm"
        },
        "body":{
            "additionalProperties":false,
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "mission_id":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "pattern":"^(MISSION)([0-9]{17})$"
                },
                "command":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "enum":[
                        "CREATE",
            "CANCEL"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required":[
                "mission_id",
                "command"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required":[
        "header",
        "body"
    ],
    "additionalProperties":false
}

This configuration of schemas checks that the messages that are sent have a header and a body and both of those have the correct configuration.
An example:
{
    "body":{
        "mission_id":"EJ_1",
        "command":"CREATE",
        
    },
    "header":{
        "id":"EXAMPLE_ID001",
        "verb":"POST"
    }
}

The thing is that the header is the same for all type of messages so I wanted to reference it.
As you can see, the second one checks the header configuration in the other file using an absolute path.
However, when I try to validate the schema I get this error message:
Check that the format follows the schema (wms_mission.scm). [header: is missing but it is required, body: is missing but it is required]
I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.
I tried playing with the relative path but I only got exceptions or it give it back as "correct".
Any idea of how to reference another JSON schema file from a JSON schema?

What library are you using for the validation? How were you calling it, what values did you pass?

I'm pretty sure the $ref should not start with a # (to reference internal definitions) but have an absolute (file) URL

@Bergi removing the # makes the error dissapear. But the configuration in "header" doesn't get checked.
So if something is wrong in the header it doesn't get check.

Again, how are you doing the checks? Does the library you use support loading arbitrary other schema files by path? Is the path even correct?

this really depends on the implementation used. Which one are you using?
The JSON Schema spec recommends all schemas to be used in the validation process should be made available prior to validation.  https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-9
Most implementations have the ability to "register" or "load" a schema prior to validation
The proper referencing of the other schema is to use the $id of the other schema directly. There are some subtleties with regards to base uri resolution and such if you have defined a different base uri for each schema. In your example, it doesn't appear you've done that.
{
    "$schema":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id":"wms_mission.scm",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "header":{
            "$ref": "header.scm"
        },
        "body":{
            "additionalProperties":false,
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "mission_id":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "pattern":"^(MISSION)([0-9]{17})$"
                },
                "command":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "enum":[
                        "CREATE",
            "CANCEL"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required":[
                "mission_id",
                "command"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required":[
        "header",
        "body"
    ],
    "additionalProperties":false
}


I'm currently using this: https://files.inductiveautomation.com/sdk/javadoc/ignition80/8.0.0-beta/com/inductiveautomation/ignition/common/jsonschema/JsonSchema.html#IGNITION_SCHEMA_PATTERN
Which I think it's a java implementation of the schema validator. Not sure.
I'll try your idea later. Thanks a lot for the info and the references!
